# How to print the coordinates of all the objects in an image, in python

Tags: python, image

I am new with Python and I am having some difficulties with image processing...

I have an image with several points. I labeled them so I can know their coordinates (x,y). However I need to do a print for each object so I can know the place of each one of them:

```
print 'obj [0]:', obj[0].centroid #(x,y)
print 'obj [1]:', obj[1].centroid
print 'obj [2]:', obj[2].centroid
print 'obj [3]:', obj[3].centroid
print 'obj [4]:', obj[4].centroid
(...)
```

I want to know how many objects do I have in my image and then print the coordinates of all of them with only one print command.

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

```
for i in range(len(obj)):
    print 'obj [%s]:' % i, obj[i].centroid
```

Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), you can iterate an iterable with indice:

```
for i, o in enumerate(obj):
    print 'obj [%s]:' % i, o.centroid
```